# error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error on Vue.Js Project

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have an error with my Vue Project when i run "npm run serve/build" syntax in terminal.

My npm node version is at v18.12.0 (with npm 8.19.2)

The error message is:

```
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

I have try to search the solutions, but many solution is for React and its not working.

Comment: try NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider npm serve/build

Comment: @YidelBraver thanks its work now. So i should use this for every run serve?

Comment: try to run this in power shell $env:NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your script tag with this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Comment: not working for me